# When generating images, what are the advantages of DBM over GAN?

Tags: machine-learning, mnist, generative-adversarial-network

According to what I know DBN and GAN are both generative models. So when generating images and classifying, what are the advantages of DBN over GAN? Is GAN almost always better than DBN? Thank you!

Comment: you mean dmn-pls correct title